# iOS: Custom password as fallback for biometrics

Tags: swift, keychain, ios14

I would like to protect a keychain item with biometrics, allowing the fallback to be a previously set password instead of the device pin.

So whenever accessing the secret item from the keychain, the user should be presented the biometrics prompt; if successful, the content gets read. If not successful/cancelled, I would love to have a custom password prompt instead of the device pin to unlock the data.

(How) is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Is that all you want to know?

Comment: no, that's why there's also the "how"

Comment: Your question as to 'how' is way too broad.

Comment: how can I improve it then? Does "combining applicationPassword and biometry" make it clearer?

Comment: Maybe set your `SecAccessControlCreateFlags` to `[.or, .applicationPassword, .userPresence]` or something along those lines?

Comment: hm... maybe I did it wrong, but didn't work for me: `SecAccessControlCreateWithFlags` return `nil` then